# PHP pass variable to hidden field

Tags: php, simplexml, php-5.3

Ok, I am using PHP to parse XML file and to display it;s context to HTML. Here is the code.
Sample text is - Don't Give UP!

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('data/quotes.xml');
            foreach ($xml as $quote) {
                $text = $quote->text;
                echo '<div class="itemWrapper">'.
                            '<div class="quoteHolder">'.
                                    '<p class="quote">'.$text.'</p>'.
                            '</div>'.

                            '<form class="selectionButtons">'.
                                    "<input type='hidden' value='$text' name='quote'>".
                                    '<input class="submitButton" type="button" value="create your design">'.
                            '</form>'.
                     '</div>';
            }
```

So, when I use $text variable in paragraph it display's correctly, But when I pass it to the form's hidden field I only get: Don (so it stops right before that single quote) It happens with every text that has quotes. Why is that and what is wrong here?

Comment: you need to escape the quote

Comment: I tried to escape the quote in XML file, but that doesn't make any difference. And why it displays full text in HTML paragraph?

Comment: try like this `addslashes ($text);`

Comment: meda - already tried this, no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use this one...

```
$this_text = "Don't give up!";
$text = htmlspecialchars($this_text, ENT_QUOTES);

echo "<input type='text' value='$text' />";
```

I have tested in already..

Comment: Thanks, figured this out just before saw your answer. Anyway accept it as working code. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

HTML `input` fields require that the contents be escaped. Conveniently, PHP has a function that does all the work for you:

```
$display_text = "Don't give up!";
$input_text = htmlspecialchars($text);
```

[Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

Comment: With some modifications, but works. Here is the working code - $input_text = htmlspecialchars($text, ENT_QUOTES);